# Querying PostgreSQL view via presto

Tags: postgresql, presto

I'd like to query postgresql view via presto. I've found some old links/notes that it should be possible. Unfortunately I don't have any views listed in `SHOW TABLES` command and when I tried to query data `select cnt from umcount` I got `Table 'public.umcount' not found`. How to query views then?

I'm using Presto 0.205

Comment: What's the view name in PostgreSQL? Does it contain any upper-case characters? (BTW I invite you to Presto Community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out these queries first:

`show schemas from <connector_name>`

`show tables from <connector_name>.<schema_name>`

If everything works fine then use these prefixes in your select queries.

For example:

`select * from <connector_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name> limit 10`